# Android-Expandable List

Tags: android

How to set the Height and width of group indicator in expandable list when i am using customized icons instead of default icons.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should have a image view and there you place layout_height="40dp" and layout_wight="40dp"

I think is that sorry if i din't answer well

Comment: set the group indicator using setGroupIndicator(Drawble drawable) then after run that file icon size will be big then how set the height and width.

Answer (score 0):

In your ExpandibleListView: (xml)

android:indicatorLeft="20dp" (or another size)

android:indicatorRight="20dp"